# Creating a 2 colour heatmap with Python

Tags: python, heatmap

I have numerous sets of seasonal data that I am looking to show in a heatmap format.  I am not worried about the magnitude of the values in the dataset but more the overall direction and any patterns that i can look at in more detail later.  To do this I want to create a heatmap that only shows 2 colours (red for below zero and green for zero and above).

I can create a normal heatmap with seaborn but the normal colour maps do not have only 2 colours and I am not able to create one myself.  Even if I could I am unable to set the parameters to reflect the criteria of below zero = red and zero+ = green.

I managed to create this simply by styling the dataframe but I was unable to export it as a .png because the table_criteria='matplotlib' option removes the formatting.

Below is an example of what I would like to create made from random data, could someone help or point me in the direction of a helpful Stackoverflow answer?

I have also included the code I used to style and export the dataframe.

[Desired output - this is created with random data in an Excel spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aORl1.png)

```
#Code to create a regular heatmap - can this be easily amended?

df_hm = pd.read_csv(filename+h)
pivot = df_hm.pivot_table(index='Year', columns='Month', values='delta', aggfunc='sum')      
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax.set_title('M1 '+h[:-7])
sns.heatmap(pivot, annot=True, fmt='.2f', cmap='RdYlGn')
plt.savefig(chartpath+h[:-7]+" M1.png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

```
#code used to export dataframe that loses format in the .png

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dataframe_image as dfi
#pivot is the dateframe name
pivot = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100,100,size= (5, 12)),columns=list ('ABCDEFGHIJKL'))
styles = [dict(selector="caption", props=[("font-size", "120%"),("font-weight", "bold")])]
    pivot = pivot.style.format(precision=2).highlight_between(left=-100000, right=-0.01, props='color:white;background-color:red').highlight_between(left=0, right= 100000, props='color:white;background-color:green').set_caption(title).set_table_styles(styles)
dfi.export(pivot, root+'testhm.png', table_conversion='matplotlib',chrome_path=None)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually set `cmap` property to list of colors and if you want to annotate you can do it and it will show same value as it's not converted to -1 or 1.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

arr = np.random.randn(10,10)
sns.heatmap(arr,cmap=["grey",'green'],annot=True,center=0) 
# center will make it dividing point
```

Output:
[image: heatmap]

PS. If you don't want color-bar you can pass `cbar=False` in `sns.heatmap)

Comment: Thanks Godwin.  This would definitely solve the annotation.  However it does not segregate between positive and negative values.  In the case of your example I would want only values below zero to be grey, and only values of zero and above to be green.  is there a way to pass a criteria within the heatmap function that makes this possible?

Comment: Sorry I just overlooked it. Just a sec will make correction.

Comment: Have a look @Rich. And for other styling attribute like line width/space between each cell, line-color, and size and all you can use normal `matplotlib` attribute and have a look at [`sns.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

To achieve what you need, you just need to pass `delta` through the sign function, here's an example code:

```python
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randn(25,25)

sns.heatmap(np.sign(arr))
```

[image: Output Heatmap]

Which results in a binary heatmap, albeit one with a quite ugly colormap, still, you can fiddle around with Seaborn's colormaps in order to make it look like excel.

Comment: Thanks Neervana.  This gives me exactly what I need in terms of the colours.  If I wanted to maintain the values of the original data to annotate the heatmap is there a way to annotate with the original data?  obviously the solution you present means the values will be -1 or +1.  Not a big deal if this is not possible.